# clearing an <a> href after the page is loaded using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I'm trying to slightly modify a wordpress template.  At the moment a function returns a link to an article, I am trying to replace this link so that instead of diverting you to another page it just brings the article in and loads it.

To do this I need to reset the anchors href after the page has loaded.

This is the bit of code I am interested in:

```
<?php the_content( __('<img class="readmore" src="/images/readmore.png" title="poo"></img>', 'twentyten' ) ); ?>
```

returns:

```
<a class="more-link" href="http://henryprescott.com/undgraddissintro/#more-12">
<img title="poo" src="/images/readmore.png" class="readmore"></img></a>
```

However I want to modify this so a script runs instead of taking you to a new page.

I therefore tried to run this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  

  $("a.more-link").css("href", "#");
  alert($("a.more-link").css("href"));
}
```

It does nothing, and the alert returns "undefined".

Where am I going wrong, thanks!

Comment: CSS has nothing to do with this. You are trying to manipulate a DOM-node, which cannot be achieved with styles. Take a look at jQuery's [`.attr()`-method](http://api.jquery.com/attr/).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to change the attribute with a CSS command, which is wrong.

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
  $("a.more-link").attr("href", "#");
  alert($("a.more-link").attr("href"));
}
```

Answer (score 15):

Use `attr()` instead of `css()`.

The `css` method is for getting or setting CSS properties (like `margin`, `color`, `font-size`, etc.). The `attr` method is for getting or setting HTML attributes, like `href`, `src`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

the css() if just for adding inline css, try attr() in this case

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){  
jQuery("a.more-link").attr("href", "#");
alert(jQuery("a.more-link").attr("href"));
return false;
}
```

the return false is to avoid the page reload. ;)